# ORB Feature matching detect false image

Tags: android, opencv, knn

i am trying to make a currency detection application using android and Opencv and i am using ORB detector and knnMatcher as follow :

```
detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.ORB);    FastFeatureDetector.create(FastFeatureDetector.THRESHOLD,false,FastFeatureDetector.TYPE_9_16);
  matcher= BFMatcher.create(BFMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING,false);
String fullPath = "/storage/emulated/0/Currency Resources Folder/"+"50-front.jpg";
 Mat blured_src = new Mat();
            Mat blured_test = new Mat();
            Mat resized_test = new Mat();
sizeToScale =1 ;
            Imgproc.resize(mGray,resized_test,new Size(mGray.width()*sizeToScale,mGray.height()*sizeToScale));
Imgproc.medianBlur(img_src,blured_src,3);
            Imgproc.medianBlur(resized_test,blured_test,3);

            Mat canny_src = new Mat();
            Mat canny_test = new Mat();
            Imgproc.Canny(blured_src,canny_src,50,200);
            Imgproc.Canny(blured_test,canny_test,50,200);
            MatOfKeyPoint kp_test = new MatOfKeyPoint();
            MatOfKeyPoint kp_src = new MatOfKeyPoint();
            detector.detect(blured_test,kp_test);
            detector.detect(blured_src,kp_src);
Mat desc_src = new Mat();
        Mat desc_test = new Mat();
        descriptorExtractor.compute(blured_src,kp_src,desc_src);
        descriptorExtractor.compute(blured_test,kp_test,desc_test);
List<MatOfDMatch> matches = new ArrayList<MatOfDMatch>();
        matcher.knnMatch(desc_test,desc_src,matches,2);
LinkedList<DMatch> good_matches = new LinkedList<>();

        for (Iterator<MatOfDMatch> iterator = matches.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
        {
            MatOfDMatch next = iterator.next();

            if (next.toArray()[0].distance / next.toArray()[1].distance < .92)
            {
                good_matches.add(next.toArray()[0]);
            }
        }
List<Point> pts1 = new ArrayList<Point>();
        List<Point> pts2 = new ArrayList<Point>();
        for(int i = 0; i<good_matches.size(); i++){
            pts1.add(kp_test.toList().get(good_matches.get(i).queryIdx).pt);
            pts2.add(kp_src.toList().get(good_matches.get(i).trainIdx).pt);
        }
 Mat outputMask = new Mat();
        MatOfPoint2f pts1Mat = new MatOfPoint2f();
        pts1Mat.fromList(pts1);
        MatOfPoint2f pts2Mat = new MatOfPoint2f();
        pts2Mat.fromList(pts2);
if (pts1Mat.toList().size() != 0 && pts2Mat.toList().size() != 0) {
            Mat Homog = Calib3d.findHomography(pts1Mat, pts2Mat, Calib3d.RANSAC, 15, outputMask, 2000, 0.995);

LinkedList<DMatch> better_matches = new LinkedList<DMatch>();
            for (int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++) {
                if (outputMask.get(i, 0)[0] != 0.0) {
                    better_matches.add(good_matches.get(i));
                }
            }
MatOfDMatch matches_mat = new MatOfDMatch();
            matches_mat.fromList(better_matches);
MatOfByte mask = new MatOfByte(outputMask);
            Features2d.drawMatches(mGray, kp_test, img_src, kp_src, matches_mat, output,new Scalar(255,0,0),new Scalar(0,255,255),mask,Features2d.NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS);
            if (Imgcodecs.imwrite("/storage/emulated/0/Currency Resources Folder/match" + counter + ".jpg", output))
//////        if(SaveImage(output,"/storage/emulated/0/Currency Resources Folder/match"+counter+".jpg"))
            {
                Log.e(tag, "Match image saved");
            }
            Log.e(tag, "matches = " + better_matches.size());


            counter++;

return mRgba ;
}
```

and i am facing those issues :

1. matches list is always 40 and 60 points for correct and wrong
   objects
2. the matcher detect false objects like my keyboard and produce a
   matched image
3. i can not recognize if the matcher already detect the currency
   paper or it just detect a false object ( like my computer keyboard )
4. i need to put a boarder around the currency and detect it right
   every time

out put images will describe better what i want to explain 
[image]

Comment: matching will always find the best matches, even if those best matches are wrong or very bad. Typically you try to detect wrong matches with additional assumptions like assuming the best and 2nd best match may not be too similar and like computing a homography that should agree with all correct matches.

Comment: so how to detect that i found the correct object ?

Comment: compute the homography from the matching and check whether it makes sense (size change, coverage in both images, etc.)

Comment: make a list of unique features which describe the key points in the currency and while iterating through matched key points in the scene image check for those unique features to reduce false positives.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the threshold of your detector so it is less sensitive to the background noise. You can further improve the detector's performance by discarding high distant matches.